# SiteMapMvc not working With two parameters in static url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, sitemap

I have Route Config In My Asp.net Mvc Application as below :

**RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default2",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
```

And I have three controller : **Articles** , **DevSection** and **Home**

```
  [SiteMapTitle("title")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        objlstproc = getproc();
        Proc objproc = objlstproc.Find(s => s.id == id);
        return View(objproc);
    }
```

and my Site Map Code is

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="DevSection" controller="DevSection" action="Index" key="DevSection">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Articles" controller="DevSection" action="Article" key="Articles">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title=""  controller="Articles" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="id,title" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Now I use from

```
  @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

In my Layout , I get this error

> The node with key 'Articles_Articles_Index_GET__' does not have a 'title' set. Title is a required field for every node.

So I Set default string for title for Below row with xxx string

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="xxx "  controller="Articles" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="id,title" />
```

Now work application fine  and now i want go to Articles Controller and Index action with this url :

```
http://localhost:3754/Articles/index/1/whatever
```

I get this error

> The node with key 'Articles_Articles_Index_GET_xxx_' may not add a route value with the key 'title' and value 's' to the RouteValues dictionary because the key is a reserved name. Reserved names are keys that are meant for use internally by MvcSiteMapProvider rather than a dictionary value.

Valid keys may be "area", "controller", "action", and custom parameters that are not the same as property names of ISiteMapNode.

You may suppress this error message by calling an overload of the RouteValues.Add() or RouteValues.AddRange() that accepts the 'throwIfReservedKey' argument and passing false for the value. Note that if you do this, attempting to add a key with a reserved name to the RouteValues dictionary will silently fail.

But  if I use from  http://localhost:3333/Articles/index/1 
Or
http://localhost:3333/Articles/index?id=1&&titile=ds

site map work form me fine...

**But I want just use from 
 http://localhost:3754/Articles/index/1/whatever 
in my site.**

thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change title name to  t (whatever) . because title is a key  or reserved in sitemap and conflict with my route title for example :  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{t}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, t = UrlParameter.Optional } do not thank me , thanks God